# PHP File Upload + ID from Form

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

i've put together a script and all seems well except for the actual upload of the file.  Here is the php code that I have:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["avatar"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["avatar"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    header("Location: ../../dashboard.php?page=profile&error=true");
    }
    else
    {
    $newfilename = "uwhduwhd";
    $path = "../../avatar/";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $newfilename); 

    header("Location: ../../dashboard.php?page=profile&error=false");
    }
}
else
{
header("Location: ../../dashboard.php?page=profile&error=true");
}
?>
```

What I also want to do is have the $newfilename as an ID that is passed through the form on the previous page, using

Can someone please help? Thank you

Comment: what problem you are getting?

Comment: what is issue you found and where you want to use the id

Comment: The problem is that I am getting an error for the More_uploaded_files and no file is being moved - I want the id to go where the $newfilename is

Comment: Since you are using `in_array` for extensions, why not use it for `$_FILES["avatar"]["type"]` too?

Comment: Do you have write permissions to `$path = "../../avatar/";`? You are never checking the return from `move_uploaded_file()`, then you do a redirect with `header()` so that could be the issue. Side note, you should follow `header('Location: ...');` with an `exit;` otherwise the rest of the code is still executed.

Comment: Thanks @Tigger _ I'm working on localhost so I presume have permission. Other than that I can't understand why this isn't working

Comment: Is there maybe a better way of writing this code?

Comment: No, you may not have permission as the web server runs as the "web" user, not the local logged on user. What happens when you change `move_uploaded_file(...)` to `print_r(move_uploaded_file(...))` and comment out the following `header()` line.

Comment: @Tigger I still get the same error

Comment: And, what is that error again? Can you update your question with the exact error that is displayed.

Comment: @Tigger I'm getting the header("Location: ../../dashboard.php?page=profile&error=true"); return which is at the bottom of the script above

Comment: That is not an error message, I (and anyone else) needs to see the error message that is displayed by PHP to the page.

Comment: @Tigger There is no error message being displayed - That's the reason I can't understand why this isn't working

Comment: Change: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $newfilename); header("Location: ../../dashboard.php?page=profile&error=false");` to `$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $newfilename); echo 'result:['.$result.']; \\header("Location: ../../dashboard.php?page=profile&error=false");` and tell me what is in the `result:[]` line.

Comment: @Tigger Again No error, but as it's returning the last header error it looks more likely that it's something to do with the $extention section at the top?

Comment: Well, comment out both `header()` calls and before each add `echo 'error point 1';` and `echo 'error point 2';` and then you will know for sure.

Comment: @Tigger Yes it's Error Point 2 - So it's not running the first section properly